# How to deliver large payloads (ie. more than 150 KB) to other functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, orchestration

While reading the data from function , the result for that is more than 130KB so for that I'm getting an exception of "The UTF-32 size of the JSON-serialized payload must not exceed 60 KB. The current payload size is 130 KB." What to do because I want to deliver that larger amount to data to other function?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyoTS.png)

Comment: Which trigger are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has fixed this size limitation problem : [Enabling large message support. #242](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/pull/242)

You might want to do an "update" on the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions Nuget in your project.
Should be OK from version 1.1.4 beta onward.